# Triple product and the first invariant of a tensor.

Tags: tensors

$\mathbf{T}$ is a second-order tensor, and $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are vectors. Prove $$[\mathbf{T} \cdot\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}]+[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}]+[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{w}]=J_1(\mathbf{T})[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}]$$
where $J_1(\mathbf{T})$ is the trace of tensor $\mathbf{T}$.
I tried index notation but it brings me nowhere. Is there any clue?

Comment: What is $[\cdot,\cdot,\cdot]$?

Comment: It means tripe product.$[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}]=\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$

Answer (score 0):

Check this site on the index notation derivation.
https://nptel.ac.in/courses/112103167/module1/lec5.pdf[image]